# Match depending on preceding letters

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regex to match Word2 only if Word1 preceeds it without space and both words have to start with a capital letter?

Like this:

```
Word1Word2
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `/Word1(Word2)/`?

Comment: Hi @anubhava not sure what you mean. Word1 and Word2 could be any word anywhere in a sentence. I was hoping there would be a generic pattern that matches word2 even though the condition is not part of the match.

Comment: Have you considered learning how regexes work?

Comment: Looks like this `Word1(Word2)`  should work. The problem is what part of `Word1` and `Word2` is variable and what part isn't. When you can decide that, it's still the same pattern with modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and sorry for the unclear question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex pattern to match the second word:

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

This pattern works if the first letter of each word is capital and the rest of the letters in the word are uppercase,lowercase or digits